# How can I record Adobe Flash Player stream

Tags: video-recording, video-capture, digital-recording, live-recording

I am learning English and I want to record [this stream](https://youtu.be/Bpc2jmNpL78).

It's using Flash Player and in addition include PDF doc.
Thanks for your interest.

[image]

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Can you ask the question in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser plugin such as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/.

When you go to the page after installing, an icon will alert you to downloadable media and provide you different formats if they are available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about legal part of downloading video from youtube... But you can do it without installation of any side softwere:

Write "ss" in the link before "youtube.com" part. So, if it was

- https: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bpc2jmNpL78

Make it

- https: //www.**ss**youtube.com/watch?v=Bpc2jmNpL78

Wait a little bit, and you will see download link:
[image]

Comment: sorry,you misunderstanded me I want download flash player video and in addition include with PDF doc